# Помогите решить задачу по вычислению полинома

Tags: c++, visual-c++, математика, ряды

Задача такая...
Ввести e (точность, например 0.0012), m (количество членов полинома, например, 25) и x (например, 3).

Вычислить значение функции: [image: функция]
Как это реализовать?

**Обновление**

Мой вариант простой, обычная функция, но неправильная.

```
float ex=0, znam=4, chisl=1, _item= 1/4, sumx = 1, n=0;
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {       
        sumx += (_item *= (((chisl += 4)*pow(x, ex +i)) / (znam += 4)));
        printf("%.8f\n", sumx);
}
return sumx;
```

Надо как можно проще сделать.

Comment: ну, так а ваши варианты??? Мой вариант написать класс полином. Описать из чего он состоит. ну и подставлять свои значения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мда... Зачем просто, если можно сложно? :)

Проблема в том, что надо решать - или точность, или число членов. Одновременно и то, и другое - нонсенс. Если нужна точность - то можно прекращать цикл при члене, меньшем заданной  точности (но это оценка не самая строгая... ряд при `x>=1` вообще расходящийся). Можно написать по достижению того, что раньше произойдет - будет достигнута точность, или просчитано заданное количество членов. Словом, дерзайте :) Правьте предложенный вариант - который выводит значения для разного числа членов:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    double a = 1.0;
    double sum = a;
    double x;
    int m;

    cout << "m = ";
    cin >> m;

    cout << "x = ";
    cin >> x;

    for(int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    {
        a *= x*(4*i+1)/(4*i+4);
        sum += a;
        cout << "n = " << setw(4) << (i+1) << "  Sum = " << setw(12) << sum << endl;
    }

}
```